# Abrir una carpeta del ordenador con JAVA

Tags: java, windows, cmd

En el siguiente código estoy creando una clase la cual crea en el ordenador una carpeta y ademas agrega un jPanel con diferentes opciones, lo que pasa es que al momento de pulsar el botón *START* debería abrir la carpeta, pero he intentados varias formas sin obtener resultados.

```
public class Carpeta extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private String direccion = "C:\\Users\\capri\\Privados\\";
    private String user;
    private String nombre;
    private JLabel etiqueta;
    private JCheckBox ocultar;
    private JCheckBox visible;
    private JButton start;

    public Carpeta(String user, String nombre, String estados) {
        setSize(400,100);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));
        this.etiqueta = new JLabel(nombre);
        this.user = user;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        ocultar = new JCheckBox("OCULTO");
        visible = new JCheckBox("VISIBLE");
        if(estados.charAt(0)==1){
            ocultar.setSelected(true);
        }
        if(estados.charAt(1)==1){
            visible.setSelected(true);
        }
        start = new JButton("INICIAR");
       start.addActionListener(this);
        visible.addActionListener(this);
        ocultar.addActionListener(this);

        add(etiqueta);
        add(new JSeparator());
        add(start);
        add(ocultar);
        add(visible);

        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object ejec =  e.getSource();

        ***en esta parte****************************************
        if(ejec == start){
            String urlm = direccion+nombre;
            ProcessBuilder p  = new ProcessBuilder();
            p.command("cmd.exe ","\\c",urlm);
        }   
       *************************************************************
       if(visible.isSelected()){
           try{
               Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib -s -h "+direccion+nombre);
               }catch(IOException ex){}
           ocultar.setSelected(false);
       }else{
           ocultar.setSelected(true);
       }
       if(ocultar.isSelected()){
            try{
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +s +h "+direccion+nombre);
                }catch(IOException ex){}
            visible.setSelected(false);
        }else{
            visible.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
}
```

también he utilizado lo siguiente, pero ni aun así logro que abra la carpeta

```
    if(ejec == start){
        try{
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start "+direccion+nombre);
            }catch(IOException ex){}
    }
```

si alguien pudiera ayudarme y a la vez explicarme cual es el motivo de que no funcione mi cidigo.

Comment: te recomiendo utilizar `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\folder"));` mas info en [Desktop Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) en lugar de `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` luego. que exactamente pasa ? da algun error?

Comment: simplemente no hace nada, sigue el programa pero no se abre la carpeta, ahora probare con lo que me dices!!

Comment: @Silencio2 probe con lo que me recomendaste y abre sin ningun problema, muchas gracias, de igual manera no sabes porque de las otras formas no abre?, vi en varias paginas que les funcionaba sin ningun problema.

Comment: si, hice una prueba. y ` p.command("cmd.exe ","\\c",urlm);` esto no ejecuta puesto olvidaste el `p.start()` pero ademas esto no funciona puesto `("cmd.exe ","\\c",urlm);` no inicia un navegador de archivos sino una consola sino que inicia un command line. en el cual no realiza un `open` folder.  sino que "navega" al folder en consola.  para y en especifico de windows requiere ` `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+direccion);` y esto... pues no es ideal es mejor usar `Desktop.getDesktop().open()` que ademas te sirve en cualquier os que soporte Java..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como exprese en los comentarios el Problema que experimentas es por que el Process no inicia (no se llama a `p.start()`) como #1, ademas para llamar un Folder debe utilizar algo asi: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+direccion);` pero en todo caso, es mejor utilizar `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\folder"));`

PERO! ademas dado lo que intentas hacer con el el applicativo voy a incluir algunas recomendaciones para Ademas hacer que esta applicacion no sea Dependiente de commandos de Windows:

```
//imports relevantes: 
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.DosFileAttributeView;

//...
//codigo del UI (no hay cambios con respecto al codigo provisto)  
//...

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object ejec = e.getSource();
    Path path = Paths.get(direccion,nombre);
    if (ejec == start) {
        showfolder(path);
    }
    flipSwithes();
    cambiarAttributo(path,visible.isSelected());
}

/**
 * metodo que despliega el folder/archivo
 * @param path el folder/archivo a desplegar
 */
private void showfolder(Path path) {
    if (!Files.exists(path)) {
        System.out.printf("el archivo < %s > no existe", path.toString());
    } else {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(path.toFile());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Carpeta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * cambia el attributo de visibilidad del archivo/folder 
 * @param path direccion del archivo/folder
 * @param visible si debe o no ser visible
 */
private void cambiarAttributo(Path path,boolean visible) {
    DosFileAttributeView dosView = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, DosFileAttributeView.class);
        try {
            if (dosView.readAttributes().isHidden()!=!visible) {
                dosView.setHidden(!visible);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Carpeta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}

/**
 * configura los checkboxes de visible/ocultar.
 */
private void flipSwithes() {
     if (visible.isSelected()) {
        ocultar.setSelected(false);
    } else {
        ocultar.setSelected(true);
    }
    if (ocultar.isSelected()) {
        visible.setSelected(false);
    } else {
        visible.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

y a este punto no nesesitamos ejecutar nada fuera de codigo de Java. :)

[Disk Operating System FileAttributeView javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/DosFileAttributeView.html)

[referencia de como usar Disk Operating System FileAttributeView](https://dzone.com/articles/java-nio2-file-attributes)

[uso de Desktop Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File))